# MySQL row as a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query result and I would like the **second row for each id** to be added as a

```
SELECT m.post_id,m.meta_value,p.post_title 
from events_posts p
inner join events_postmeta m 
on p.ID=m.post_id and p.post_type='event' and (p.post_status='publish' or p.post_status='recurring') 
and(m.meta_key='address' or m.meta_key='st_date')
order by m.post_id
 column.
```

The **results right now :**

```
post_id meta_value  post_title
15  Carolina Beach Road, Wilmington, NC, United States  An Art Exhibition
15  2014-02-03  An Art Exhibition
19  Dakota Street, Winnipeg, MB, Canada Weekly Karate Classes
19  2014-02-06  Weekly Karate Classes
23  Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA, United State  Christmas Carnival
23  2014-02-03  Christmas Carnival
```

I would like it to be

```
post_id | meta_value| post_title

15  | Carolina Beach Road, Wilmington, NC, United States    | An Art Exhibition   | 2014-02-03  
19  |Dakota Street, Winnipeg, MB, Canada    |Weekly Karate Classes |2014-02-06   
23  |Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA, United State |Christmas Carnival |2014-02-03
```

Comment: Can you please add the description of the `events_postmeta` table?  I assume there's a metadata name field which can be used to distinguish between `address` and `date` metadata which can be used as part of the join criteria to have two logical joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually **not** trying to convert rows to columns. You are trying to merge two rows of your query into one. This behaviour should be possible through joining the events_postmeta twice.

```
SELECT p.ID, m1.meta_value as event_address, m2.meta_value as event_date, p.post_title 
from events_posts p
inner join events_postmeta m1
on p.ID=m1.post_id and p.post_type='event' and (p.post_status='publish' or p.post_status='recurring') 
and m1.meta_key='address'
inner join events_postmeta m2
on p.ID=m2.post_id and p.post_type='event' and (p.post_status='publish' or p.post_status='recurring') 
and m2.meta_key='st_date'
order by p.ID
```

That way the `m1`-join adds the address as a column and the `m2`-join adds the date. I could not test this but I am pretty sure it works (modulo some typing syntax mistakes).