# SQL Query to transpose data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table in SQL Server 2008:

```
ID  Type    Value
6   A_Left  A
6   B_Left  B
6   C_Left  C
6   D_Left  D
6   E_Left  E
6   A_Right A
6   B_Right B
6   C_Right C
6   D_Right D
6   E_Right E
```

And I need to get them grouped based on Value column like:

```
ID  Type    Type    Value
6   A_Left  A_Right A
6   B_Left  B_Right B
6   C_Left  C_Right C
6   D_Left  D_Right D
6   E_Left  E_Right E
```

Is this possible? I am not getting exact terms on what such transpose is called to google.

Comment: You can select two times the same table but for the first you gget only the registries with 'Left' string same for the Right then you join the two of then by the value which seems the same.

Comment: It feels like I answered that question recently. Maybe check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584468/mysql-row-as-a-column/21584589#21584589).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `INNER JOIN`, join the table against itself. On one side of the join, limit to those matching `_Left` and on the other side, limit to those matching `_Right`.

```
SELECT
  l.ID,
  l.Type AS L_Type,
  r.Type AS R_Type,
  l.Value
FROM
  t l
  INNER JOIN t r ON l.ID = r.ID AND l.Value = r.Value
WHERE
  RIGHT(l.type, 4) = 'Left'
  AND RIGHT(r.type, 5) = 'Right'
```

Here's a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6590/4

Alternatively, you may use `LIKE` rather than the `RIGHT()` string function:

```
SELECT
  l.ID,
  l.Type AS L_Type,
  r.Type AS R_Type,
  l.Value
FROM
  t l
  INNER JOIN t r ON l.ID = r.ID AND l.Value = r.Value
WHERE
  l.type LIKE '%_Left'
  AND r.type LIKE '%_Right'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f6590/5

Comment: I would use LIKE instead of RIGHT function: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8cc08/6 but since you posted first :) (no need of distinct, edited.)

Comment: @JorgeCampos I was just making a second fiddle using `LIKE`.

Comment: just use this one then :)

Answer (score 1):

Using PATINDEX :

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Type As Type, t2.Type AS Type, t1.Value As Value 
FROM t as t1 JOIN t t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID AND t1.Value=t2.Value
WHERE PATINDEX('%_Left',t1.Type)>0 
AND PATINDEX('%_Right',t2.Type)>0
```

Similar to above but Using CTE AND LIKE (PATINDEX Can also be used) :

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    Select ID,Type,Value FROM t WHERE Type LIKE '%_Left'
)

SELECT t1.ID,CTE.Type+ ',' + t1.Type As Type,t1.Value FROM CTE
JOIN t t1
ON t1.ID = CTE.ID AND t1.Value = CTE.Value 
WHERE  t1.Type LIKE '%_Right'
```